# Creating a SOAP php request with a ssl certificate to an asp.net web service keep getting soapfault:forbidden

Tags: php, asp.net, ssl, nginx, soap

I have been attempting to make a soap call from my **nginx server with php** towards an asp.net webservice. Current php version is 5.5. The service we are communicating with uses https and (for testing purposes) our server is using http for the moment.
They are behind a firewall and the relevant ip addresses  have been white listed. I am using the php built in soapclient to make the requests.
When i access the wsdl link in my browser or if i print it out in php i can see the xml so i can confirm that part is working. I tried using SoapUI but they dont support SNI.
I have created an ssl key which the web service party has signed and then i combined this with my private key into a .pfx certificate so i can use to make a soap call for creating an account. When i tried to make a soapcall to create an account i get the error soapfault:forbidden

Here is my code for creating the soapclient:

//settings at the top of the page

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 180);

$this->options = array(
    'local_cert'=>  file_get_contents($this->smartcard_cert),
    'passphrase'=> $this::pass,
    'trace' => 1,
    'exceptions' => 1,
    'keep_alive' => 0,
    'connection_timeout' => 20
);

$this->soap = new SoapClient($this::protected_wsdl, $this->options);
```

And this is my function for doing the call:

```
public function create_current_acccount_get($reference = 233423) {
    $values = $this->transaction_handler->createCurrentAccount($reference);
    try {
        $response = $this->soap->CreateCurrentAccount($values);
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        $response = $e->getMessage();
    }

    log_message('error', print_r("code4554 ".$response, TRUE));

    $this->response($response);
}
```

I can't display the xml sadly because it is confidential.
I understand that nginx uses .pem instead of .pfx but the webservice only accepts .pfx.

If anybody has any idea as to why the forbidden soapfault is being cause i would be eternally greatful, because this has been bugging me for 4 days already and i haven't been able to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/goetas-webservices/soap-client is fully PHP SOAP client that does not rely on the `ext-soap` from PHP.

It already supports is PSR7, multiclient and allows to have generated classes for type-hinting via your IDE.

https://github.com/goetas-webservices/soap-client-demo is demo project that allows you to see how to use the client to consume a generic SOAP webservice.

And since is multiclient, you can use the Guzzle (or any https://github.com/php-http compatible client) options to provide the transport layer